# How to disable TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 on Apache

Tags: apache2, ssl, https, tls

I have enabled TLS 1.2 in my web server. But the http://ssllabs.com indicates that, I have enabled TLS 1.0 and 1.1 versions along with the TLS1.2 in my server. I modified my configurations files to disable 1.0 and 1.1 from my server. But it doesn't help.

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf

SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!SSLv3:!kRSA:!kECDH:!ADH:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
```

I have multiple virtual hosts in my Apache server. In each file, I have the following configuration.

```
SSLEngine On
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/certfile.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/certfile.pem
```

Comment: I too am currently having this issue on Ubuntu 16.04. Trying to disable TLS 1.0 as auto-renew from lets encrypt won't work at some point in future if TLS 1.0 still enabled.

Comment: I noticed that I am running apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 and according to this post, it might be a case that there is a bug where apache does not honor the SSLProtocol lines. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437546/disabling-tls-1-0-in-apache-2-4

Comment: @Programster Is your server located in AWS ?  " SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.2 " controller works fine. It must work. Try to figure-out if there is any chance to have two certificates configured in your server unknowingly.

Answer (score 12):

Look in the /etc/letsencrypt/ folder for a configuration file. Let's Encrypt adds an entry in the sites-enabled/-le-ssl.conf file:

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

You will need to update the SSLProtocol & SSLCipherSuite directives in that file too.

Comment: Hey there, in the question is not defined letencrypt is used.

Comment: You are right. It's in the first comment. Oops.

Comment: @bernieDog Still helpful though, I was getting fustrated with this issue until I saw this answer. Thanks!

Comment: You're a legend, I was struggling to work this out too.

Answer (score 4):

Letsencrypt by default will write this in `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf` .
Check to make sure is included in your server configuration.

```
SSLEngine on    
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

**Open this file and edit as below.**

```
SSLEngine on

#we comment out whatever Letsencrypt give here
#SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
#We disabled TLS 1.0/1.1 and SSL 2.0/3.0 here
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 

#Comment out whatever Letsencrypt give by default for SSLCipherSuite
#SSLCipherSuite    ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 .....

#Add this line instead of what Letsencrypt added as SSLCipherSuite
#This is to ensure the use of SSL encryption with a high degree of protection.
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES

SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off
```

**Go back to the [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and Clear Cache. Then re-run the Test**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With a current Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, we have Apache 2.4.29 and the problem is not reproducible.

The following configuration in `/etc/apache2/sites-enables/default-ssl.conf` switches off the unwanted protocol versions:

```
# Suppress TLSv1.0 and TLS v1.1
SSLProtocol +TLSV1.2 +TLSv1.3
```

I put it close to the end of the file before `</VirtualHost>`.

Answer (score 0):

Enable and disable TLS options

> sudo nano /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

```
SSLProtocol             all +TLSv1.3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

And run test again!

Answer (score 0):

In your virtual-host config, Edit This line

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -SSLv2 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

Note that in configuration file, another file maybe included, so you can edit that.